# Согласование местоимения «который» с определяемым словом

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

Предложение:

"Ищите людей, разговор с которыми стоил бы хорошей книги, и книги, чтение которой стоило бы любого разговора".

Правильно ли во второй части предложения местоимение *которой* использовано в единственном числе, в то время как слово *книги*, на которое оно ссылается, – во множественном. Или же все-таки это можно счесть за нежелательный вариант и лучше так не делать?

Comment: Вообще не понимаю смысл предложения, какой-то бред. Как разговор может стоить книги? И как чтение книги может стоить любого разговора? Первое ещё можно как-то воспринять: отдать хорошую книгу, чтоб поговорить (бред).

Comment: По-моему, мысль совершенно ясная.  Общайтесь с умными людьми и читайте хорошие книги –  такое общее и такое чтение сравнимы с точки зрения пользы для вашего развития.

Comment: Вот оно что. Но структура ужасная. Может, интернет-переводчик переводил? Надо переформулировать. Например: *Ищите людей, разговор с которыми был бы сопоставим с чтением хорошей книги, и книги, чтение которых было бы сопоставимо с любым разговором.* Дело в том, что "стоил бы" в первую очередь воспринимается так: отдай одно, чтоб получить другое (оно стоит того).

Comment: @oleed, предложение взято из книги "Эксперт ЕГЭ. Руссий язык" и, как я понимаю, является сокращением от высказывания Пьера Буаста "Ищите людей, разговор с которыми стоил бы хорошей книги, и книг, чтение которых стоило бы разговора с философами". Где вы тут видите ужасную структуру мне, если честно, непонятно. 

Источник: https://ru.citaty.net/tsitaty/462193-per-buast-ishchite-liudei-razgovor-s-kotorymi-stoil-by-khoroshei/"

Comment: Ну всё понятно, ужасный перевод с французского. Далеко не всё на русском может нормально звучать. Не может разговор стоить книги. Разговор даже не может быть сравним с книгой, другое дело — с чтением книги. То, что там не "книги", а "книг", уже говорит о неграмотности перевода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ищите людей, разговор **с которыми** стоил бы хорошей книги, и книги, чтение **которых**  стоило бы любого разговора.*

Пояснение

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с двумя **определительными придаточными** и союзными словами "которыми, которых".

Главное предложение: *Ищите людей и книги*.

Союзное слово  "который" в этих предложениях является **дополнением.** Оно согласуется с определяемым словом **во мн.числе**, а падеж (Т.п. и Р.п.) ему задают существительные (разговор и чтение) в придаточном определительном предложении.

Ищите людей (каких?), разговор с которыми (то есть с такими людьми) стоил бы хорошей книги, и книги (какие?) , чтение которых (то есть таких книг) стоило бы любого разговора.

Answer (score 0):

Это предложение правильно, но лучше так не делать — авторы других ответов воспринимают "книги" как форму мн. ч. вин. п., хотя по "которой" видно, что это форма ед. ч. род. п. — она ведь иногда употребляется с этим глаголом, в качестве примера можно привести фразеологизмы «от добра добра не ищут», «ищи ветра в поле» и др.

Comment: "Ищите книги, чтение которой..." вообще не звучит, так не говорят.

Comment: Не звучит, но с точки зрения грамматики всё правильно.

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Не всегда возможен родительный падеж. При глаголе "искать" родительный уместен, когда существительное абстрактное и неточное, как в вашем первом примере. Родительный чаще всего употребляется при отрицании. Не стоит приводить в пример пословицы/фразеологизмы, потому что в народной речи нормы часто нарушаются.